# Read JSON keys from XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using xslt to build a xml message. I'm getting input from a JSON message to build the XML message.

My JSON message.

```
{
 "aaaa":"123456",
 "bbbb":"ENG",
 "gen":"F"
}
```

I'm using xsl:stylesheet 2.0.

This I how to tried to do that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions" xmlns:m0="http://services.samples" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="m0 fn">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="*">
  <header>
     <consts>
        <branch>account</branch>
     </consts>
     <message>
        <seo>
           <xsl:template match="node()[name(.) = 'bbbb']">
              <xsl:value-of select="fn:string(.)" />
              <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
           </xsl:template>
        </seo>
     </message>
  </header>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But, this can't read the JSON value correctly. What is modification should I do to the XSLT file?

Comment: Attempting to nest `xsl:template` inside of another `xsl:template` should give you a compilation error in any XSLT version/with any XSLT processor. XSLT 1 and 2 are mainly for processing XML, it is not clear in which context you use XSLT (2 as you say) to process a "JSON message". Either an extension is provided or some on the fly JSON to XML transformation is done before your XSLT runs. It entirely depends on your environment how JSON is mapped to XML so nobody can suggest the right XSLT code unless there is a clear spec as to how your JSON input is mapped to XML.

Answer (score 0):

JSON support comes only in XSLT 3.0.

JSON objects aren't represented as nodes, they are represented as maps and arrays.

If you've read your input JSON using `json-doc('my.json')` then you can access the value of the `aaaa` field using `json-doc('my.json')?aaaa`.